# Byte Array to Word Array to String

Tags: c#, string, arrays, ushort

I have this `byte[]: 00 28 00 60 00 30 10 70 00 22 FF FF`.

I want to combine each pair of bytes into a word: `0028 0060 0030 1070 0022 FFFF`.

I also want to turn the word array into a string: `"0028 0060 0030 1070 0022 FFFF"` (without using `byte[]`).

I fixed SLaks code and it works:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(var i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
   sb.AppendFormat("{0:X4} ", words[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
StringBuilder words;

for(int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i += 2) {
    if (i > 0) words.Append(' ');
    words.AppendFormat({0:X2}{1:X2}", bytes[i], bytes[i + 1]);
}
```

**Edit**: For `ushort`s:

```
StringBuilder words;

for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) words.Append(' ');
    words.AppendFormat({0:X4}", ushortArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: That's going from byte[] to string, and is good to know, but wanted to know how to deal with word array (ushort[]).